# find non duplicated item in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays built from different directories that contain file names stripped of extensions. I want to find the ones that don't make a pair thus I merged the array to obtain the array below. How can I find the only ***non* duplicate** item in an array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_06_27
    [1] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_07_08
    [2] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_13_33
    [3] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_15_24
    [4] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_21_57
    [5] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_22_11
    [6] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_08_40_35
    [7] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_08_41_36
    [8] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_08_43_38
    [9] => dbbackup_2014.09.04_04_59_08
    [10] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_06_27
    [11] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_07_08
    [12] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_13_33
    [13] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_15_24
    [14] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_21_57
    [15] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_07_22_11
    [16] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_08_40_35
    [17] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_08_41_36
    [18] => dbbackup_2014.09.03_08_43_38
)
```

Note: it is [9]

Comment: Although it is one line code to remove duplicates from an array but in your case what tells a duplicate? You mentioned its index 9 but most of the other values look unique too. Is it based on Only Date?

Comment: did u tried array_unique?

Comment: It would be easier if hadn't joined the two directory list arrays. See array_diff, and compare both dirlists vice versa.

Comment: array unique simply gives me 1-8, i need to get 9

Comment: @Alex array unique will get you all the values once, which means repeated values will not be included. [As you can see here, it gives you the values up to 9 which is right as everything past it is a duplicate.](https://eval.in/188085)

Comment: i'm aware, i meant i ONLY need **9** as I need to figure out the ones not paired

Comment: @mario went with your approach. `array_merge(array_diff($arrOfSql, $arrOfFiles), array_diff($arrOfFiles, $arrOfSql));`

Comment: What do `$arrOfFiles` and `$arrOfSql` have to do in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $data)
{
    $values=explode("_",$data);
    $output[$values[1]]++;
}

foreach($output as $date=>$number)
{
     if($number==1)
     echo $date; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014.09.04
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/188094)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array_flip(array_filter(array_count_values($a),function($item){
    return $item == 1 ? true : false;
}));
print_r($a);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => dbbackup_2014.09.04_04_59_08
)
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/lM6L56)